# Split mySQL results over two <div> and limit to 4

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a question that relates to adverts that are stored in a mySQL database. I need to fetch all the results, sort by the id descending limit to 8 and then display 4 results in one <div> and the other 4 in another <div>.

Here's my current code:

```
 <div id="first_adverts">
 <?php $i = 1; ?>
 <?php $getAdverts=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE live = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8");
          while($showAdverts=mysql_fetch_array($getAdverts)) {

          $checkdate = $showAdverts['expiry_date']; // Date From Advert in Database
          $checkdate = strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$checkdate)); // Change Date format to 01-07-2013 instead of 01/07/2013
          if ($checkdate > time()) { // If date is in the future (EG the advert hasn't expired) then show:

          $showAdvertiserData=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM advertisers WHERE id = '".$showAdverts['advertiser_id']."'")); ?>
      <div class="advert-cell">
        <a href="#" class="topopup_<?php echo $i; ?>">
         <img src="images/adverts/<?php echo $showAdverts['image']; ?>" width="200">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="toPopup_<?php echo $i; ?>">

        <div class="close"></div>
        <div id="popup_content">
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <h1>Contact <span class="green"><?php echo $showAdvertiserData['company_name']; ?></span></h1>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <form id="advertenquiry<?php echo $i; ?>" name="advertenquiry<?php echo $i; ?>" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validateAdvertEnquiryForm<?php echo $i; ?>()">
            <input name="advertiser_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $showAdverts['advertiser_id']; ?>">
            <input name="advert_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $showAdverts['id']; ?>">
            <p><input name="enquiry_name" type="text" id="name" value="Name *" onFocus="clearMe(this)" style="width: 250px;" /></p>
            <p><input name="enquiry_telephone" type="text" id="telephone" value="Telephone *" onFocus="clearMe(this)" style="width: 250px;" /></p>
            <p><input name="enquiry_email" type="text" id="email" value="Email *" onFocus="clearMe(this)" style="width: 250px;" /></p>
            <p><textarea name="enquiry_query" id="query" cols="45" rows="5" onFocus="clearMe(this)" style="width: 300px;" >Query </textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="enquire" value="Send" class="submit_button" /></p>
          </form>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php } } ?>
 </div>

<div id="second_adverts">
<?php // second set of ads here ?>
</div>
```

As you can see this shows all 8 results and then checks to see if the advert's expiry date is in the future or not. Basically I need the above code to show the first 4 results and then the last 4 separately later on the page. (There would be a bit more HTML in between the two queries)

Comment: Where is the loop here

Comment: Sorry some of the code wasn't showing

Comment: You said you want to sort descending, but your query has "ASC."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a single query:

```
$query =    "SELECT 'adverts.id', 'adverts.advertiser_id', 'adverts.image' 'advertisers.company_name'
             FROM adverts
             LEFT JOIN advertisers ON adverts.advertiser_id = advertisers.id 
             WHERE((expiry_date > NOW()) && (live = 1))
             ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8";
$count = 0;
while($showAdverts=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)) {
    if ($count < 4){
        //display first four
    } else {
        //display second four
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution I used earlier in my project.

1) Fetch all the record and store into a php array

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(YOUR_QUERY))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

2) Now Using `foreach()` loop use data fetched from query where ever you want

```
if(is_array($rows)) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        //do with $row or create some if,switch condition here !
    }
}
```

For specific limits and tweaks study the result set we get from `mysql_fetch_array()` !

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not just make an if (i <= 4) -> write it in the first div or (else) write it in the second div?